# image doesn't display from database (MySQL/php)

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

Everything is coming from a PDO and is well displaying with the exception of the image.
I wrote the folder's path in the DB as if it was written after a src=

As a beginner in php, i'm wondering if it's the good way to display a picture

EDIT:
images are in jpg,
console shows a "404" but with the good path

```
<?php
try {
    $bdd = new PDO(/*the pdo works*/);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM equipepedagogique');//where the picture is
?>
 <div class="enseignants"><!--grid-->
            <!--case-->
            <?php 
            while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch())
            foreach ($donnees as $donnee) { 
                $img=$donnees['photo'];
                $nom=$donnees['name'];
                $prenom=$donnees['surname'];
                $fonction=$donnees['fonction'];?>
            <div class="enseignant">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img?>" alt="" class="photoEnseignant">
                </a>
                <h1 style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><?= $prenom .' '. $nom ?></h1>
                <p><?= $fonction ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is $img a path or a binary value? if it is a binary value print sample value you read from database in the question.

Comment: What does `$img` contain?

Comment: $img is supposed to display the path of the picture in the folder from the database, stocked with a TEXT type.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
try {
    $bdd = new PDO(/*the pdo works*/);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM equipepedagogique');//where the picture is
?>
 <div class="enseignants"><!--grid-->
            <!--case-->
            <?php 
            ***while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch())*** **//while($donnees=$reponse->mysql_fetch_array())**
            foreach ($donnees as $donnee) { 
                $img=$donnees['photo'];
                $nom=$donnees['name'];
                $prenom=$donnees['surname'];
                $fonction=$donnees['fonction'];?>
            <div class="enseignant">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img?>" alt="" class="photoEnseignant">
                </a>
                <h1 style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;"><?= $prenom .' '. $nom ?></h1>
                <p><?= $fonction ?></p>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: thanks , but it doesn't work.
but $nom, $prenom and $fonction are displayed